# Writing a file with lock() java

Tags: java, pdf, locking, pdfbox, fileoutputstream

I'm using PDFbox to try and write over an existing empty pdf. I'm new to using lock() and can't figure out how to write to the file in that instance so I can write the information to it. I think I need a ByteStream somewhere but can't figure out how to use it.

```
File pdfexport = new File(filename);
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(pdfexport, "rw").getChannel();

        if (pdfexport.exists()) {

                FileLock lock = channel.lock();

                FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(channel.write());
                //The above line says there is an error which there probably is.


                documentnew.save(fop);

                lock.release();
                channel.close();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting at: "FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(channel.write());"

Comment: the write() function requires a ByteBuffer. So write(ByteBuffer) but I'm not sure how to use ByteBuffer when trying to save my file.

Comment: Whats the idea behind this? Simply create a FileOutputStream.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I'm working with another programmer and he suggested using this as a backup to make sure the right data is written to the right file.